# Storing binaries elsewhere in Git

Tags: git, storage, binaries

Like a lot of people I use Git with binaries and none of the existing solutions seem to work for me ( git plugins like git-annex, git-lfs, git fat, etc…, submodules/subtrees (it just moves the problem elsewhere)).

So I’ve been thinking of using filters for clean and smudge:

For clean:

```
#!/bin/bash
dest=/g/MO-F1/user/binary_folder
mkdir -p $dest
tmpfile=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/tmp
cat > $tmpfile
sha=$(git hash-object --no-filters $tmpfile)
mv $tmpfile $dest/$sha
echo $sha
```

For smudge:

```
#!/bin/bash 
source=/g/MO-F1/user/binary_folder
tmpfile=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/tmp 
cat > $tmpfile 
sha=$(cat $tmpfile) 
cat $source/$sha 
rm $tmpfile
```

And I modified .gitattributes so the corresponding binaries are managed by the filter (in my case .jpg and .png)

So the scripts work and the binaries are stocked in G:\MO-F1\user\binary_folder (a Group share hard drive) as blob and are not put in the .git folder!
But when I clone the corresponding repository (and add as well the two scripts and modify the .gitattribute), I cannot access to these blobs but only the “pointer”, even when I check-out.

How could a clone of the repository access correctly the files in the group share?

Thanks for your response I hope I’ve been clear enough

Comment: What is the reason you use git with binaries instead of a dependency tool?

Comment: It's the firm policy and unfortunately I cannot change it.

Comment: This is not necessarily a bad thing.   Binaries are just frowned upon because they don't compress well.  What exactly does the firm policy say you have to do?

Comment: To keep using Git as DVCS, but to store binaries elsewhere and to keep them accessible at any time, and every versions (so we will not have a .git Folder very huge that are really slow, which is the case now).

Comment: Sounds like a very big network drive which is backed up properly.

Comment: I don't understand how this is different than git-lfs or git-media, which are exactly this:  filters that store the binary assets separately.  What do you mean when you say that git-lfs (for example) "moves the problem elsewhere" and how is this different?

Comment: "moves the Problem elsewhere" was about Subtrees and Submodules
git-lfs and git-media are not compatible with our environment and our server unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing with the effort to write script to move blob to another folder, I would prefer to save all of those binary files in another git repository. By using another repository, you can manage it by git submodule or [repo tool](https://source.android.com/source/developing.html)

Comment: But storing the binaries in another repository and manage it by a submodule doesn't solve anything. I will have 2 repository, one with the code and the other with the binaries. I need to keep the binaries with the source code  as they are linked together, often modified, and I need to keep all the different versions of the binaries.

Comment: @Theologie You can specify branch/tag in .submodules (for git submodule) or manifest.xml (for repo tool).